# wrap page title property in <span> tag

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have an aspx  page title tag like the following :

```
<title> XXXX-content page title </title>
```

I need to dynamically set the title tag of my Page from code behind like the following:

```
<title> <span itemprop="name"> XXXX-content page title</span> </title>
```

My question is : How do I dynamically insert(wrap) the "XXXX-content page title" part of the title in a span tag??
I tried doing this :

```
     Page.Title = "<span itemprop=\"name\">"+ XXXX-content page title + "</span>";
```

but it renders the span tag within the quotations.
How can I do this without using Jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the `itemprop` attribute directly on the `title` element:

```
<title itemprop="name">XXXX-content page title</title>
```

However, mostly the page contains, or should contain, a main heading that is to appear as part of the page. It is probably more common to have the relevant text there. And within that heading, you *can* use inner markup:

```
<h1>span itemprop="name">The key part of the heading</span> more stuff</h1>
```

In general, you need not add `span` elements for microdata, if there is an element in markup that contains just the text to be used.

Answer (score 1):

Title tag cannot include other HTML tags? Following to the [HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/struct/global.html#h-7.4.2):

> Titles may contain character entities (for accented characters,
>   special characters, etc.), but may not contain other markup (including
>   comments).

Comment: hmm...I wonder why schema.org asked me to wrap it in the span tag for "microdata tagging" purposes in that case.

Comment: I have no idea, but HTML specification is clear on that point.

Comment: @karry You confuse ! ask you to include what you call as Title, not the <title></title> ! For example the header title of your product must be inside the itemprop="name"

Comment: @karry the microdata tagging ask you to place the itemprop="name" where you have the header/title of your product, not inside the <title> tag. Do you get it now ?

Comment: Question is about aspx page title so it's about title tag as I see the examples. If you looked at my link you'd see it's about that tag.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can't add `span` tag between title tag.
For what reason did you need to add `span` ?

Comment: for "microdata" tagging purposes...if you know about schemaorg and its microdata tags, they suggest you do that to your title tag so that the search engines grasp it.

Answer (score 0):

all you need to do is ...

```html
<title id="title" runat="server"></title>
```

... and then in your codebehind ...

```cs
title.Text = "I set this title in code-behind";
```